# How to query multiple projects in one shot using Google cloud Gcloud queries in google cloud sdk

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have multiple projects in Google cloud and I need to find-out unused external ip address in all the projects. I have a query which works for one project but is there a way to run a query which runs on all projects together.

I am trying to avoid time and effort for switching projects every time.

Command to extract reserved pip's in a single project - `gcloud compute addresses list --filter=status:reserved`

Answer (score 1):

For a process like this, It would be better to create a script that runs this for you! One great thing about gcloud commands is that they can be used in shell languages to help make things like this possible!
Open cloud shell in GCP, create a file called "script.sh" and write something like this to the file...

```
#The below line will do an action for every project in the project list
for project in $(gcloud project list --format='(project_id)');
     do
          #This gcloud command will run for every instance of project in projectlist
          echo $(gcloud compute addresses list --project=$project --filter=status:reserved)

     #ouput to csv
     done >> output.csv
```

once this is done, make sure to grant yourself permission to run this script by typing...

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

then run the script...

```
./script.sh
```

Let me know if this helps! Comment to this answer if you need more clarification or help!

Comment: Here is a link [https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud] to the GCP documentation on scripting with Gcloud! Give it a read, it will be really helpful!

Comment: Says ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'project'.